# Spring Websocket message pushing

Tags: java, websocket, tibco, spring-websocket, tibco-topic

I am using spring 4 web socket and TIBCO JMS Queue for my application,   In that, we are listening to JMS (TIBCO) queue , receiving data and adding to Collection. At the same time we are intended to send the data to web socket clients consecutively. I am using MessageSendingOperations template to send the data to clients. even though flow goes without any error, data is not received to clients.

Listener (on Message) code snippet here:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) throws NullPointerException 
{

    String sMsg = ((TextMessage) message).getText();  

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(); 

    JsonObject jsonOrderObj = (JsonObject) parser.parse(sMsg); 

     Order order = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOrderObj, Order.class); 
     this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/sample", new Response(mapper.writeValueAsString(order )));  
}
```

Please share your ideas on this.

Comment: could you share you client code and server side WebSocket configuration?

Comment: how are you configuring the messagingTemplate?